# How to debug an Android app that "unfortunately stops"?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have posted my code and the errors below:

```
package com.example.chirag.numgame;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TV);
TextView score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
Button upbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.upbutton);
Button downbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.downbutton);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
    Button upbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.upbutton);
    Button downbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.downbutton);
    generate();
}
void generate()
{
    int number = (int)Math.random();
    TV.setText(number);
}
}
```

I cannot find the error in this code.

> 07-17 12:58:56.518 30381-30381/com.example.chirag.numgame I/Process:
>   Sending signal. PID: 30381 SIG: 9 07-17 12:59:13.823
>   3894-3894/com.example.chirag.numgame D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down
>   VM 07-17 12:59:13.825 3894-3894/com.example.chirag.numgame
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.example.chirag.numgame, PID: 3894
>                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.chirag.numgame/com.example.chirag.numgame.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.view.Window$Callback
>   android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:72)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:193)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:173)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:511)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:183)
>                                                                                 at com.example.chirag.numgame.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:9)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1089)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)

Answer (score -1):

Declare variable outside the method and bind the views in the `onCreate()` method:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView TV;
TextView score;
Button upbutton;
Button downbutton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TV);
    score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
    upbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.upbutton);
    downbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.downbutton);

    generate();
}
void generate()
{
    int number = (int)Math.random();
    TV.setText(number);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't find a component in a view when the view has not been created. Also, I can see only the TV is used as global variable. So you can switch it to the code below, haven't tried but hopefully it should work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView TV;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TV);
    TextView score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
    Button upbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.upbutton);
    Button downbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.downbutton);
    generate();
}
void generate()
{
    int number = (int)Math.random();
    TV.setText(number);
}}
```

Comment: I tried what you said, but the app on my phone just won't open. all it says is "Unfortunately yourapp has stopped".